# How do I deconstruct this object of objects of objects into object of objects?

Tags: javascript, object

I have let's say this object

```
const obj = {
  background: {
   backgroundColor:{
    background: '#ffffff'
   },
   backgroundImage:{
    background: 'url(...)'
   }
  },
 header:{
  logo:{
   width: '100%'
  },
  title:{
   color: '#000000'
  }
 }
}
```

And I need to deconstruct it into something like this:

```
const deconstructedObj = {
   backgroundColor:{
    background: '#ffffff'
   },
   backgroundImage:{
    background: 'url(...)'
   },
   logo:{
    width: '100%'
  },
   title:{
    color: '#000000'
  }
}
```

This is just an example, my objects are bigger, but idea is the same, first keys need to be deconstructed, how do I do that?

Comment: Maybe the way to look at it is the first keys need to be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would get you there, since you only want the values of the outer objects. [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) will grab those inner objects into an iterable array and [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) will help concatenate them all into a single object result

```
Object.values(obj).reduce( (b,a) => ({...b, ...a}),{})
```

```js
const obj = {
  background: {
    backgroundColor: {
      background: '#ffffff'
    },
    backgroundImage: {
      background: 'url(...)'
    }
  },
  header: {
    logo: {
      width: '100%'
    },
    title: {
      color: '#000000'
    }
  }
}
const decon = Object.values(obj).reduce( (b,a) => ({...b, ...a}),{})
console.log(decon)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only certain keys, or your needed keys are nested at various levels, you can try something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  background: {
   backgroundColor:{
    background: '#ffffff'
   },
   backgroundImage:{
    background: 'url(...)'
   }
  },
 header:{
  logo:{
   width: '100%'
  },
  title:{
   color: '#000000'
  }
 }
}


const { background: { backgroundColor, backgroundImage }, header: { logo, title } } = obj;

const destructuredObj = {
  backgroundColor,
  backgroundImage,
  logo,
  title
}

console.log(destructuredObj)
```